# Can I generate fields automatically in eclipse from a constructor?

Tags: eclipse

When I'm coding in eclipse, I like to be as lazy as possible.  So I frequently type something like:

myObject = new MyClass(myParam1, myParam2, myParam3);

Even though MyClass doesn't exist and neither does it's constructor.  A few clicks later and eclipse has created MyClass with a constructor inferred from what I typed.  My question is, is it possible to also get eclipse to generate fields in the class which correspond to what I passed to the constructor?  I realize it's super lazy, but that's the whole joy of eclipse!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have a class A.

```
class A{
    A(int a |){}
}
```

| is the cursor. *Crtl + 1* *"assign parameter to new field"*

Result:

```
class A{
    private final int a;
    A(int a){
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

This works also for methods:

```
    void method(int b){}
```

Will result in:

```
    private int b;
    void method(int b){
        this.b = b;

    }
```

Comment: How to use this with multiple fields? For instance if I have 5 fields and I want to generate this fields only in one move

Comment: Minor note: for me, this didn't result in a `final` field. Your first example suggests it does.

Answer (score 4):

I know you can do the other way round. Define the fields and let Eclipse generate a constructor using these fields for you: `Source | Generate Constructor using Fields`

Comment: Very useful, I'm sure I'll use this even though it wasn't quite what I was after today.

Answer (score 2):

Since Eclipse Neon it is possible to assign all parameters to fields.

Using the quick assist <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> it suggest `Assign all parameters to new fields`. You can call for the quick assist if the cursor is anywhere between the parenthesis of the constructor.

This option is available for methods as well.

[source](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/jdt.php#assign-all-params-to-new-fields)