# Eclipse Shortcut to create fields in POJO from parameterized constructor?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not sure if it makes sense to put this question, but when I am developing **Spring Boot + Axon + CQRS**, I always need to create a fields (member variables) from the constructor of the class. Any quick eclipse short-cut to help me with this?

I've seen people do from the **IntelliJ Idea**. Something can be achieved in eclipse/STS?

**ComplaintFileEvent.java**

```
public class ComplaintFileEvent {

    public ComplaintFileEvent(String id, String company, String description, ....) {

    }

}
```

**Any eclipse shortcut to import static imports?**

Comment: Place the cursor to the parameter, hit Ctrl+1 and choose _Assign parameter to new field_ or _Assign all parameters to new fields_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I generate fields automatically in eclipse from a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789137/can-i-generate-fields-automatically-in-eclipse-from-a-constructor)

Comment: Thanks working perfectly